# How do I return string as well as IEnumerable<T> from same method in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, extension-methods, overloading

I have one generic method which does some operations and want to
return result as string or `IEnumerable<T>`

```
  public IEnumerable<T> MyResult(string input)
  {
      // do something return string based on some
      // case or return IEnumerable<T>
  }
```

How do I achieve this in one method, and how do I maintain return type?

Comment: As you probably have found, a method can have one return type.  Add an out parameter or create a DTO containing the enumerable and string and return that.

Comment: You'll have to add some context.  You can't do what you're suggesting, but I can't see what what you're suggesting is particularly useful.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: A method can not have multiple return types.

Even though this is bad design you could (A) add an out parameter or (B) create a DTO containing the enumerable and string and return that.

(A):

```
public IEnumerable<T> MyResult(string input, out string output)
{
    // do something 
}
```

(B):

```
public MyDTO MyResult(string input)
{
    // do something 
}
```

and

```
public class MyDTO 
{
    public IEnumerable<T> resultAsEnumerable {get; set;}

    public string resultAsString {get; set;}    
}
```

Comment: @cubrr 
A DTO is a **d**ata **t**ransfer **o**bject. 
[link]http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use `object` as return type of your function, then you can return either a `string` or an `IEnumerable<T>` depending on the input. Something like this:

```
public object MyResult<T>(string input)
{
    if (true)
        return "string";
    else
        return return new List<T>() { default(T) };
}
```

Comment: That is a horrible design.. please don't do this.

Comment: also: this would always return "string" because true is always true. don't do this!

Comment: @ChrisM Of course he would insert is own conditions there ...